# Is it possible to have a border around a table row in some way?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to add borders around specific table rows which change it's colors when the mouse enters the row. However, I don't see a border at all unless using `border-collapse:collapse;` but I have to avoid border-collapse, since in some cases the border is visible left, right and at bottom but not on top (probably because I cannot have padding/margin when using border-collapse).

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr style="border:1px solid black">
    <td>Cell_1</td>
    <td>Cell_2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I can see border with and without _border-collapse:collapse;_

Answer (score 12):

You can try using `outline` instead.

```
tr:hover {
    outline: 1px solid #999;
}
```

Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dWWkx/3/

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exacly I was looking for. However, I dont see the borders with Google Chrome, while Firefox 3.6 displays it as expected. Strange...

Comment: @wdguru Hmm... the problem with the outline property is that its used more as a debugging tool than anything else, since the position of the border is not defined clearly in the specs. Its possible that Webkit does not support outline on `tr`  - IE 7 and below does not support this at all. See: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/outline

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't put a border on a table row, but you can on the table cell (`<td>`).
With some creative border-right and border-left, with a cell-spacing of 0, you should be able to achieve the appearance of a border around the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same problem and found this workaround:

```
<tr class="border_bottom">
```

CSS:

```
tr.border_bottom td {
   border:1pt solid black;
}
```

Found it here and adjusted it: [Add border-bottom to table row <tr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<table style="">    
   <tr style="display:block;border:1px solid black">    
      <td>Cell_1</td>    
      <td>Cell_2</td>    
   </tr>    
   <tr style="display:block;border:1px solid black">    
      <td>Cell_1</td>    
      <td>Cell_2</td>    
   </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this before. The problem with display:block is, that the row isn't streched as it would be with display:table-row.