# row border color

Tags: html, css

I want to set the border of `<tr>` to yellow. I can set the border of `<td>` but can't figure how to set border of row `<tr>`.
How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What you have tried until now? Any problem with `<tr style="border:solid yellow">` ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589614/is-it-possible-to-have-a-border-around-a-table-row-in-some-way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No can do, ime, even though css spec ( http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties ) plainly says border and border-color can be applied to "all elements". Though it might be because <table> might not fall under the box model; I'm not sure about this.

In any case, it's a counter-intuitive, crazy-seeming, page-bloat-inducing pita.

There must be better solutions than bordering every single table cell, which is what I end up doing.

-- pete

Comment: I think you're wrong. TR elements does accept border.

Answer (score 12):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/a5TyU/) is working fine on IE8, Chrome 9 and Firefox 3.6 so I really can't see what is the problem.

HTML used in the example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td class="middle">BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.middle { border: 2px solid blue; }
tr { border: 2px solid red; }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

It **does** work, and by the spec.
The problem is that the borders collapse, and you did not expect that.

And by the spec the border for `td` tends to dominate over the border for `tr`:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution

Answer (score -1):

Write a CSS rule for the tr element? Something like tr {border: ...} Have you tried this and it's not working? Validate your HTML code first with the W3C markup validator and solve the errors if there are any indicated.

Answer (score -1):

I did it without css.

`<TR BORDERCOLOR="RED" BGCOLOR ="PINK">`[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylUI0.png)

works in IE but not firefox,chrome or even edge.