# Add border-bottom to table row <tr>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table of 3 by 3. I need a way to add a border for the bottom of every row `tr` and give it a specific color.

First I tried the direct way, i.e.:

```
<tr style="border-bottom:1pt solid black;">
```

But that didn't work. So I added CSS like this:

```css
tr {
border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
}
```

That still didn't work.

I would prefer to use CSS because then I don't need to add a `style` attribute to every row.
I haven't added a `border` attribute to the `<table>`. I hope that that is not affecting my CSS.

Comment: As a side note, if inline styling (first example in your question) isn't working then it's unlikely that embedded styling (second example) will work. You should also research the availability of attributes for the element you're attempting to style: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html

Comment: If you want to have a border bottom for table's tr you can follow this http://jsfiddle.net/7awN4/

Comment: Just a note to encourage future searchers to scroll down to @Nathan Manousos's answer, below - it's probably the solution you're looking for

Answer (score 479, accepted):

I had a problem like this before. I don't think `tr` can take a border styling directly. My workaround was to style the `td`s in the row:

```html
<tr class="border_bottom">
```

CSS:

```css
tr.border_bottom td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Note that using this solution you will most likely have a gap in the border between td's. [simoncereska's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10040974/2098939) takes care of this but be aware that it may not look nice with dotted or dashed border types (because they're not continuous)

Comment: You could also remedy this by adding `cellspacing="0"` as an attribute to `<table>` (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/670571/2521769)). Don't know how this will look with dotted or dashed borders, though.

Comment: `tr` can take border styling in the collapsing border model. @Sangram, consider accepting an answer which takes that into account instead of this one, no?

Comment: This will not work if there is padding between the table cells. If there is padding then the border will visibly be split int pieces.

Comment: and your table need this style <table style="border-collapse:collapse">

Comment: This answer feels hacky. The answer by Nathan Manousos is far more elegant, fit for purpose, and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 773):

Add [`border-collapse:collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) to your table rule:

```
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

#### Example

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>A1</td><td>B1</td><td>C1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>A2</td><td>B2</td><td>C2</td></tr>
</table>
```

[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)

Comment: This does not work by itself. You still can't style the row, but you can style the cells.

Comment: You are wrong, @Renan . The collapsing border model is exactly what makes row borders stylable. According to [CSS sectoin 17.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders): In the separate border model “Rows, [...] cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those elements).” “In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that surround all or part of a cell, row [and] row group [...]”  And by the way: it does work in my browser (Chromium 37).

Comment: I think some people might be getting confused (like I did) and aren't noticing that the border-collapse style needs to be set on the table, not the row.

Comment: Seems that Chrome does not have this feature, though it support others of border-collapse features.

Comment: This removed the padding.

Comment: I have been trying to get a solid bottom row line to work and I either lose my padding and margin or I get no border. How do I get both ?

Comment: This works, but boy is it dumb. I don't understand why you can't style `<tr>` all by itself. This is the kind of thing that I will *never* remember because it is completely unintuitive.

Answer (score 83):

Use `border-collapse:collapse` on table and `border-bottom: 1pt solid black;` on the tr

Comment: setting border on the tr is useless even with border collapsed. you have to set it on the tds of the tr

Comment: @RaduSimionescu Wrong, it works perfectly fine on the `tr` with border collapsed.

Comment: No effect in FF 45.0.1.

Answer (score 56):

Use

`border-collapse:collapse` as Nathan wrote and you need to set

`td { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }`

Comment: Thats the way I would do it too! Add the border on the td and use border-collapse on the table

Answer (score 42):

There are lot of incomplete answers here. Since you cannot apply a border to `tr` tag, you need to apply it to the `td` or `th` tags like so:

```
td {
  border-bottom: 1pt solid black;
}
```

Doing this will leave a small space between each `td`, which is likely not desirable if you want the border to appear as though it is the `tr` tag. In order to "fill in the gaps" so to speak, you need to utilize the `border-collapse` property on the `table` element and set its value to `collapse`, like so:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `box-shadow` property to fake a border of a `tr` element. Adjust Y position of `box-shadow` (below represented as 2px) to adjust thickness.

```
tr {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.99);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I tried adding

```
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
```

alongside the

```
    tr {
      bottom-border: 2pt solid #color;
    }
```

and then commented out border-collapse to see what worked.  Just having the tr selector with bottom-border property worked for me!

**No Border CSS ex.**

[image: No Border CSS ex.]

**No Border Photo live**

[image: No Border Photo live]

**CSS Border ex.**

[image: CSS Border ex.]

**Table with Border photo live**

[image: Table with Border photo live]

Comment: `bottom-border` is not a valid CSS property. I tried the same experiment toggling the `border-collapse` property in Chrome 84.0.4147.135 on Windows. The border will only show up when the property exists and is set to `collapse`.

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
table{border-collapse:collapse}
tr{border-top:thin solid}
```

Replace "thin solid" with CSS properties.

Answer (score 6):

Display the row as a block.

```
tr {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

and to display alternate colors simply:

```
tr.oddrow {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

Comment: [**Not** a good idea](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t160487-firefox-and-style-display-block-on-table-row.html) to set `display: block` for `tr`'s.  Use `tr td { border-bottom: ... }` ad `tr.oddrow td { border-bottom: ... }` instead

Comment: display block might destroy the table layout.border-collapse:collapse on the table itself is definitly the best solution

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to

- enforce border collapse on the table
- use the TD elements styling

You can use the **::after** selector to add borders to TR :

```
table tbody tr {
    position : relative; # to contain the ::after element within the table-row
}

table tbody tr td {
    position : relative; # needed to apply a z-index
    z-index : 2; # needs to be higher than the z-index on the tr::after element
}

table tbody tr::after {
    content : '';
    position : absolute;
    z-index : 1; # Add a z-index below z-index on TD so you can still select data from your table rows :)
    top : 0px;
    left : 0px;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    border : 1px solid green; # Style your border here, choose if you want a border bottom, top, left, etc ...
}
```

It is a simple trick that I used in a scenario where I had to put spaces between table-rows so I wasn't able to add a border collapse on the table, the end result :

[image]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is the best answer, all other solutions require border-collapse: collapse; which imho is a big limitation.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution to this is [`border-spacing`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp) property:

```css
table td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>ABC</td>
   <td>XYZ</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found when using this method that the space between the td elements caused a gap to form in the border, but have no fear...

One way around this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Example of normal table data
    </td>

    <td class="end" colspan="/* total number of columns in entire table*/">
        /* insert nothing in here */ 
    </td>
</tr>
```

With the CSS:

```
td.end{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<td style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom: thick dotted #ff0000; ">`

You can do the same to the whole row as well.

There is `border-bottom-style`, `border-top-style`,`border-left-style`,`border-right-style`. Or simply `border-style` that apply to all four borders at once.

You can see (and **TRY YOURSELF** online) more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Several interesting answers. Since you just want a border bottom (or top) here are two more. Assuming you want a blue border 3px thick. In the style section you could add

```
.blueB {background-color:blue; height:3px} or
hr {background-color:blue; color:blue height:3px}
```

In the table code either

```
<tr><td colspan='3' class='blueB></td></tr> or
<tr><td colspan='3'><hr></td></tr>
```

Comment: Adding a whole table row and table cell to insert an `<hr>`? This is an _"absolute last resort"_ type of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No CSS border bottom:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <hr>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: using <hr> is surely cheating ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a border on a tr element. This worked for me in firefox and IE 11:

```
<td style='border-bottom:1pt solid black'>
```

Comment: you can't put a border on a tr. Edited answer to clarify this.

Comment: That's the simplest and most accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having the border on the `<td>` instead of the `<tr>` is usually the way to go. However, if you're working with `<td>`'s of different heights and it messes up the layout, you could apply a linear gradient to the `<tr>` to achieve the same thing

```css
table tr, table {
  border-spacing:0;
}
table td {
  padding:12px;
}

/* conventional method - applied to <td> */
table tr:first-child td {
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

/* alternative - applied to <tr>*/
table tr:last-child {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, black 1px, transparent 1px);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td border bottom</td>
    <td>(conventional)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tr gradient background</td>
    <td>(alternative)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -4):

HTML

```
<tr class="bottom-border">
</tr>
```

CSS

```
tr.bottom-border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}
```

Comment: useless without border-collapse:collapse;