# How to make the divider between rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a table and I need to have divider like at [this site](http://translate.uservoice.com/sets/35-end-user-ar/translations?filter=missing), i.e. the divider between rows must be slim and grey. I'm trying this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<table rules="rows">
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($records as $record) {
                if (isset($record['translate'])) 
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo "<td width='500'>" . strip_tags($record['language_value']) . "</td>";
                    echo "<td width='200'>" . strip_tags($record['translate']) . "</td>";
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can u post your correct html and css code.........

Comment: I have posted in my message. I don't know CSS, that is why I need your help.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<table>
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
        <td style="width:500px">foo</td>
        <td style="width:200px">bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
        <td style="width:500px">foo</td>
        <td style="width:200px">bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px dotted silver;">
        <td style="width:500px">foo</td>
        <td style="width:200px">bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is inline CSS. Let me know if you need a CSS classes solution.

Comment: That way doesn't work for me, I had to do something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row