# How to print text above a line?

Tags: html, css

I have to make a UI of a reciept page, in which I have to print text above the line.

Here is an example image:

[image: Example]

The option of showing underline below text by using `text-decoration` property is not working as it just displays line under the text. I also tried by setting `border-bottom` of the table but it is not working either.

What I need to do is to draw a lengthy horizontal line and I can print text above it. How can I achieve this desire result?

I need it to be IE > 7 compatible.

Comment: Did you try tile background images?

Comment: It did work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row. I guess no need to keep this question. Should I delete?

Comment: Happy for you, although you already mentioned that `border-bottom` didn't work.

Comment: @JEES I was missing something in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `input` fields with a `border-bottom` style declaration. Also, since the fields are meant for display purposes only, you should set them with the `readonly` attribute, so users cannot alter their contents.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="some text goes here" readonly>
<input type="text" value="another field" readonly>
<input type="text" value="some more" readonly>
<input type="text" value="1234" readonly>
```

**CSS**

```
input {display:block;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
```

**See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H66z8/1/)**

Note the values of the fields should be properly escaped before they are included in the HTML. For example, in PHP the values can be escaped with the `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` functions.