# How to add the background-color and how to highlight the border of <tr> I am using datatables 1.9.4 version

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

Is it possible to highlight border of `<tr>` and can we append background-color to same `<tr>` inside the table?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10040881/4375327), you can style `tr` borders if `border-collapse` is set on the table.

CSS :

```
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
tr {border:2px solid black;}
```

HTML :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see the result in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1mzqL8mq/1/).

I don't understand your question about `tr` bgcolors but maybe the fiddle above will give you the answer.

Comment: ,Thanks for the response but when i am using the border-collapse:collapse; class i am getting some vertical lines on removing the class they are disappearing..if you provide solution for this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "select" feature that highlights the entire row with a border -  `.odd` / `.even` classes preserved :

```css
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid lime;
}
table.dataTable tr.selected td:last-child {
   border-right: 1px solid lime;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td {
   border-top: 1px solid lime;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lime; 
   background-color: yellow !important;
}
table.dataTable tbody tr.selected td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
   border-left: 0px;
   border-right: 0px;  
}
```

```js
$("#example").on('click', 'tbody td', function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/z8bn8rj1/**

---

**Original answer**. This is a little bit tricky since `border-color` not is supported by / valid for `<tr>`'s in CSS.

First remove the `.odd` / `.even` classes dataTables by default are adding to table rows, simply by giving `asStripeClasses` an empty array :

```js
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
   asStripeClasses : []
});
```

Then, here an example of setting the border of `<tr>`'s lime, and the background-color yellow :

```css
/* border-bottom of the headers, they appear as first row border-top */
table.dataTable thead th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lime;
}    
/* set first column left border */
table.dataTable tbody td:first-child {
   border-left: 1px solid lime;
   border-top: 1px solid lime;
}
/* set last column right border */
table.dataTable td:last-child {
   border-right: 1px solid lime;
   border-top: 1px solid lime;
}
/* remove border between columns, alternatively set border as background-color */
table.dataTable tbody td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
   border-top: 1px solid lime;
   border-left: 0x;
   border-right: 0px;  
}
/* set last row columns border-bottom */
table.dataTable tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid lime;
}    
/* set all columns background-color */
table.dataTable tbody td {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jasjek8o/**

Comment: Thanks david one small question like can we target it to alternate <tr>'s?

Comment: by default i need to show different background color for <tr>'s if i remove .odd /.even i cant show the different  background color rather it would be same for all <tr>'s.

Comment: on target to particular <tr>'s i need to remove the .odd/.even class and append the new classes to highlight the <tr>'s border and background-color. so when i am doing that due to the presence of border-collapse attribute the class which i am trying to append is not affecting. when i am adding that attribute then i am getting vertical lines in the application

Comment: @Bhairav, OK - now I understand (I think) - have updated the answer with an example of selecting / unselecting entire rows by click, odd / even persists. You just have to change the colors.

Comment: @Bhairav, did it help or should I delete the answer?