# Add border top on a TH inside of TR of table

Tags: html, css

I am inserting border on a th inside of tr but it's not applying the border.
My code

```
<tr class="shipping">
<th>Shipping 2</th>
<td data-title="Shipping 2">
                <p>There are no shipping methods available. Please check your address or contact us if you need any help.</p>

                <p class="woocommerce-shipping-contents"><small>Military Grade Paracord Kit ×1</small></p>      
        </td>
```

and css is

```
tr {
    border-top: 9px solid red;
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add border-bottom to table row <tr>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna set a border of a `tr` element you should set the `border-collapse` of the table to `collapse`:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
tr {
    border-top: 9px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="shipping">
    <th>Shipping 2</th>
    <td data-title="Shipping 2">
      <p>There are no shipping methods available. Please check your address or contact us if you need any help.</p>
      <p class="woocommerce-shipping-contents"><small>Military Grade Paracord Kit ×1</small></p>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
tr > th {
    border-top: 9px solid red;
}
```