# Having trouble getting a border to appear at the bottom of my table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I’m trying to have padding within my table row and have a bottom border for my row.  So I have:

```
.subscription-row {
    background-color: cyan;
    min-height: 30px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 22px 16px 42px 20px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
}
```

on this HTML

```
<table id="subscriptions-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subscription</th>
            <th>Download</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even subscription-row header">
                <td class="ig-header-title ellipsis">
                <img src="/assets/s-icon-0d60471f901d65172728d3df0e793b2ee4493a529c1a1dca73409fdae56ad362.png" alt="S icon">
                <a class="name ellipsis" target="_blank" href="/scenarios/18">My Scenario</a>
            </td>  
            <td align="center"><a href="/scenarios/18/download"><img src="/assets/zip_icon-c2a0694959db12a0939d264d4283478c1f59a4b118df839d7020aca929a1df61.png" alt="Zip icon"></a></td>
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but the bottom border is not showing up the desired number of pixels away from the padding — https://jsfiddle.net/z13jdLk5/ .  How can I force my solid border on the bottom of my row only while ensuring the appropriate amount of padding that I specified?

Comment: Where is the "_padding that I specified_"? I see no styles for padding

Comment: You have successfully added a bottom border to your display looking at your fiddle. The border-bottom style 1px solid #C7CDD1 overrides anything previous. If you want a gap (padding) then you need to specify it in the TR style.

Comment: Hey Tony, .subscription-row is the class applied to my TR so isn't that the TR style your talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve padding by targeting the td inside of the subscription-row, and adding some padding to it.

```
    .subscription-row td {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
```

Do note that if you use your current subscription-row class for your subsequent row styling, it will look as if only the bottom-most row will have the transparent row color you expected it to have. That is because the top of the row border has a transparent border styling which overwrites the previous row's bottom border styling.

Look here to understand more about your current problem >> [Add border-bottom to table row <tr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr?rq=1)

Comment: Your solution isn't working -- https://jsfiddle.net/z13jdLk5/1/ .  Hover over the row and notice that the border appears under most of the row, but there are gaps to the far left and right.  I would like the border to appear under the entire row.

Comment: Hi Natalia.

The reason for the gaps to the far left and right is a combination of your border-width settings of 6px right 10px left, and also border-color: transparent.

Your top, left, and right border has a transparent border with width settings, except for your bottom border which was overrided with your border-bottom style of 1px solid  #C7CDD1.

Comment: In order to achieve what you probably wanted, you can set the right and left border-width to 0.

Comment: Hi, I want the padding to the left and right of the table row and I only want the border on the bottom so it is fine that it is transparent for the top and sides.  Pretty hard question, huh?

Comment: In that case, you can just add padding-right and padding-left to .subscription-row td. Just make sure to adjust the border-width of your transparent top and side borders accordingly so it doesn't create unexpected gaps.

Comment: Alternatively, if you only want the border at the bottom, you can get rid of all the border styling and just use a pseudo selector to choose the last subscription-row and apply the bottom border.

Example:
        .subscription-row:last-child {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
        }

Comment: If I apply padding right and left to the ".subscriptoin-row td" that will apply it to all the individual cells, which I don't want.  I only want padding to the left and right of my row.  Does that make sense?  That is different than having padding to the right and left of each individual cell.

Comment: You can try ".subscription-row td:first-child { padding-left:10px; }" and then ".subscription-row td:last-child {padding-right:10px}". Basically, for the first td for a row, add left padding of 10px, then for the last td, add a right padding of 10px