# Remove border overlap on stacked tr elements using CSS

Tags: css

I have two `<tr>` elements with different color borders. The appearance is visable in the attached picture. How can I make it so they each have their own border or in other words have the lower blue one show it's upper border as well? Preferably with css.

[image]

Comment: To do that, target the `td` elements inside.

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Adding borders to `tr` elements is kind of problematic. You should target your styles to the `td` elements inside.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/72pg7xry/

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}

tr.blue td  {
  border-top: 5px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}

tr.blue td:first-child {
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
}

tr.blue td:last-child {
  border-right: 5px solid blue;
}

tr.green td {
  border-top: 5px solid green;
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

tr.green td:first-child {
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

tr.green td:last-child {
  border-right: 5px solid green;
}
```

Here's more info on why styling `tr` is tricky: [Add border-bottom to table row <tr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr)

Comment: this didn't actually help, same effect.