# how to put a line under first row in table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a line under the first row in my table but its not working. I followed the w3 schools guide for tables but it doesnt show how to put lines. I tried to put a border on the th, but it leaves a gap in the line. when I try to put a border on the tr, it doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```css
tr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tables are only meant to be formatted via individual cells. If you try to style a `tr` tag, you need to make sure you have `border-collapse: collapse` on your `table`. To target just the first `tr` specifically, set your specifier as `tr:first-of-type` and add a `border-bottom: 2px solid black`.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:first-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try collapse borders table and after that set border to you `th`

```css
tr th{
  border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your styles

```
tr:first-child th {
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

What you're doing is selecting the "th" cells in a tables row if that row is the first child of its parent. And then you're applying the specified style.

Answer (score 0):

Check here:

[Add border-bottom to table row <tr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr)

element is not the best place to define the border.
You should define the border of the  or  elements inside.

So, give your tr element a class:

```
<tr class="myClass">
```

and then define it in the CSS like this:

```
tr.myClass td, tr.myClass th {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you are annoyed by the line not being continuous, make sure you set the cellspacing on your table to 0:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

Cheers!