# Add border to first row in a table with a specific class

Tags: css

I have the following table

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1st</td>
            <td>Anne Wright &amp; Steve Wright</td>
            <td>510 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2nd</td>
            <td>Ian Bruce &amp; Lyn Hilton</td>
            <td>472 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3rd</td>
            <td>Anne Morris &amp; Lucy Pathan</td>
            <td>469 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4th</td>
            <td>Mike Ayers &amp; Mike Gould</td>
            <td>426 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5th</td>
            <td>Alison Nichols &amp; Simon Stokes</td>
            <td>409 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6th</td>
            <td>Brian Stockdale &amp; Sheila Stockdale</td>
            <td>406 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relegated">
            <td>7th</td>
            <td>Pauline Dignan &amp; Val Rees</td>
            <td>349 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relegated">
            <td>8th</td>
            <td>Alan Lord &amp; John Thompson</td>
            <td>319 VPs</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I want to put a red border above the row that has the class "relegated".

I know that I need to apply the border on the child `<td>` tags and not the `<tr>`

I have tried

```
        .relegated:nth-child(1) td {
            border-top: 1px dashed red;
        }
```

but I get nothing. Doing

```
        tr:nth-child(7) td {
            border-top: 1px dashed red;
        }
```

does work. But I want to target it based on the class (because this is a league table and you can't get relegated from the bottom division).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add border-bottom to table row <tr>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040842/add-border-bottom-to-table-row-tr)

Comment: I'd already looked at that and came to the conclusion that the border needed to be added to the <td> children and NOT the <tr> itself. My problem is how to target the correct <tr>

Comment: The tr:nth-child(1 of .relegated) suggested by 2ju2 (see below) solves the problem of how to target the correct <tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that.
:nth-child(1 of className)

```css
tr:nth-child(1 of .relegated) td{
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
            <td>1st</td>
            <td>Anne Wright &amp; Steve Wright</td>
            <td>510 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2nd</td>
            <td>Ian Bruce &amp; Lyn Hilton</td>
            <td>472 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3rd</td>
            <td>Anne Morris &amp; Lucy Pathan</td>
            <td>469 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4th</td>
            <td>Mike Ayers &amp; Mike Gould</td>
            <td>426 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5th</td>
            <td>Alison Nichols &amp; Simon Stokes</td>
            <td>409 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6th</td>
            <td>Brian Stockdale &amp; Sheila Stockdale</td>
            <td>406 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relegated">
            <td>7th</td>
            <td>Pauline Dignan &amp; Val Rees</td>
            <td>349 VPs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="relegated">
            <td>8th</td>
            <td>Alan Lord &amp; John Thompson</td>
            <td>319 VPs</td>
        </tr>     
  </tbody>      
</table>
```

Comment: That works a treat. I never knew about the "of class" option. Interestingly, neither does my IDE (VS Code) as it is highlighting this as a syntax error.